# How to open my Postgres database to the world

Tags: postgresql, sockets, networking

I have a Postgres database running on my local laptop on port 32771 (through Docker container via VM on Mac) and the network setting of it is:

```
netstat -an | grep 32771
```

Output:

```
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.32771        *.*                    LISTEN
```

How can I enable the internet to this Postgres database, so that it can be connected to from the internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your connection is open to world the db also should be open to world. Hence if you are in a lan and your ip can be accessed from other system in lan the DB should be accessible too. To take it to next level over the internet you need to have a static ip provided from your ISP. Once you have Static ip allocated and mapped to your system the DB would be accessible outside as well.

You would need to open that particular port to internet as well. This is how you can open an application port on mac machine -

1. Open System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Firewall > Firewall
   Options.
2. Click Add.
3. Choose an application from the Applications folder and click Add. In your case it should be poster DB.
4. Ensure that the option next to the application is set to Allow incoming connections.
5. Click OK.

BR

Comment: thanks for the response. My problem is actually how to open that port to the internet ?

Comment: Updated the answer on how to open port on mac.

Comment: Glad I could be  of Help